# cURL PHP submission with Chinese characters - encoding issue

Tags: php, curl, post, encoding, submission

I am currently working on a page, that is supposed to submit data via a PHP form remotely to another server using cURL, which is in turn supposed to save the data in a text file.

All good and dandy, however, the form has fields that need to be filled in with input in Chinese. Whenever I test it, the submission is done fine, but the resulting text file on the remote server has unreadable output where the Chinese letters are supposed to be.

I record the results locally in a text file as well as doing the remote cURL submission, and the local recording is fine. Chinese characters are recorded as they should be, so my assumption is I have to change something in the cURL code I am using for the submission:

```
$data = $result;

$postdata = "data=".$data; 

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")); 
curl_exec ($ch); 

curl_close($ch);
```

The submissions work fine for English characters, but not with Chinese.

The code for the receiving script is:

```
<?php

header("access-control-allow-origin: *");

$data = $_POST['data'];

$fp = fopen("submission.txt", "a");
fputs($fp, $data . "\n\n");
fclose($fp);

?>
```

What should I change, and should it be in the cURL code or the receiving script?

Comment: all your stuff is UTF-8, right?

Comment: Yes, it is - as I said, if I add code to record it in a text file locally, it saves it just fine, Chinese displays properly. If I do it via cURL though, I get gibberish in the recorded submission.

Comment: what about the other server? it's also completely utf-8?

Comment: Meaning? The only thing on the other server in terms of accepting this submission is the file whose contents I posted above.

Comment: var_dump($postdata) on the sending script and var_dump($data) on the receiving script, and let us see

Comment: i mean the php files are themselves utf-8 too? if the other php file on the other server is encoded differently it could treat input as latin1 or some other encoding

Comment: On your curl destination script, add this line at the top of it: `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");` ... see if it makes a difference. This will set that server's internal encoding method to utf-8, if for whatever reason its not.

Comment: Will try the internal encoding method - should I insert this line before the header("access-control-allow-origin: *"); line or after it?

Comment: Just tried with it - no difference at all.